# How to use haxe macro in FlashDevelop?

Tags: flashdevelop, haxe

I am interested in adding build number in the About dialog, I read about haxe macros which would generate content at compile time ..

But, how would I use it to simply add auto increased build number? I am not sure where to start or read about this while I am using FlashDevelop, any one can help?

Answer (score 1):

Use this example as an inspiration:

```
class Test {
    macro public static function getBuildDate() {
        var date = Date.now().toString();
        return $v{date};
    }
    static function main() {
        trace(getBuildDate());
    }
}
```